# BlackBerry w/Exchange Server (not using BlackBerry Enterprise Server BES)

Tags: blackberry, exchange

I have a BlackBerry and I want to get my work email on it.  We use Exchange Server and we DO NOT have BlackBerry Enterprise Server (BES).  What are my options?  I'd like to get Contacts and Calendar synced, or at least get it downloaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service provider should give you BIS service for your Blackberry.  Once you have confirmed that you have BIS from your provider, you can follow these instructions: http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB03133

Comment: Unless your Exchange provider has POP or IMAP access enabled, T-Mobile in the US will not be able to access your email. To get around this, my Exchange admin has set up a server-side rule which forwards all messages to an account the phone _can_ access.

Answer (score 1):

Without BES, you "synch" your work email by sending a copy of every email that comes in to your BBerry.  When we first got a couple BBerries, we didn't have BES and we used multiple carriers who each had their own web interface with different options, but they both had ways to send a copy of any message sent from your BBerry to a specified email address.  It's been a couple years since we got BES and I don't recall exactly how we set it up with Rogers and With Bell, but I do remember it wasn't clean.

Then for sync'ing your Contacts and Calendar, you have to use the Blackberry Desktop software.